# Add certificate per device with Android Management API

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise

Is it possible to push certificates to a device, per device basis? I know you can set up certificates per [policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/configure-networks), but I would need to set a different certificate per device (don't ask me why, the client wants it). If that is not possible is it possible to send any kind of data to a specific device?

P.S.

I have created my own EMM with android management API. I set up all the policies, added some commands that can be used per device, and I made a portal where the client can see all the devices. This is the only thing left I can't figure out if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to have a different certificate per device with the same policy since the certificate is set up in the policy. Also it is not possible to send different data for each specific device using the same policy.